# Will multilevel page table have any advantage if we don't have secondary storage?

Tags: embedded-linux, virtual-memory

In two level address translation, it's said that the first level page table (1K entries)will always be there in main memory for a process.
Out of 1K second level page tables , only those page tables will be there in memory which are currently in use. 
Where will we store other second level page tables ( which are not currently in use) in the absence of any secondary storage (e.g. in embedded systems)?
If we can't swap out second level page tables from memory, is there  no advantage of Two level Address Translation?

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of a multi-level table for logical address translation without virtual memory is that one can have dynamic page table size (even if it is not paged out). Paging is just on possible benefit (however, systems with dedicated system address spaces can page page-tables without having nesting).

Comment: Thanx for the answer..I came to know that even without secondary storage, multilevel page tables are beneficial. This is because they give us flexibility to map only those pages of user space process which the process actually use. Generally no process use all 3GB space. So this approach will save a lot of space.